# get excel file from rest response using wslite

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I am trying to test a feature that sends an excel file (.xlsx) through a REST response. I already tried the endpoint using postman and I know that the excel is downloaded (so it works) but still I can't make the test work.

This is what I have tried so far (using wslite to read the response in the test):

```
   @Subject(ExcelController)
    class ExcelFuncSpec {
        RESTClient http

    void setup() {
        http = new RESTClient("http://localhost:33089")
    }

   void "It generates an excel"() {
        given:
        int randomId = 23
        when:
        def res = http.get([
                path   : "/$randomId/excel",
        ])

        then: "The response is OK"
        res?.statusCode == OK.value()
        res.response.data //this kinda works because it returns an array of bytes
    }

    }
```

As you can see in my comment:

```
res.response.data //this kinda works because it returns an array of bytes
```

I can get an array of bytes but what I need is a java File or InputStream that I can use to read the content of the excel file.

¿How can I get the response as an InputStream using wslite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get an array of bytes but what I need is a java File or
>   InputStream that I can use to read the content of the excel file.

If `res.response.data` evalutes to the array of bytes and you want an `InputStream` associated with those bytes then `new ByteArrayInputStream(res.response.data)` will create an `InputStream` from which you can read those bytes.